# Connect SAP Cloud Platform HANA database with Web-IDE Database explorer

Tags: hana, sap-web-ide, sap-business-technology-platform

Has anyone managed to browse a cloud hosted SAP HANA database using the database explorer in the full stack Web IDE that is as well available on the SAP cloud platform?

I can connect using my cloud foundry credentials but for some reason, I receive an empty list of HDI containers and cannot select any of the schemas on my hosted HANA. Any permissions I need to set? Would be great if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 4):

1) Switch to the "Database Explorer" perspective of the WebIDE by clicking on the respective icon in the left sidebar.

[image]
2) If no databases have been added to the Database Explorer yet, click on +(see picture) button and a dialog will prompt. In the "Add Database" dialog, search for your schema, select it and click ok to add it.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't find the "Database Explorer". Then click on the "Setting" ICON. Go to the "Extensions" option. There enable the plugin "SAP HANA Database Development Tools".